# Posting message to slack get TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["User-Agent"]

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, slack-api

I have a working slack app running as an Azure Function using NodeJS.  It is posting payloads fine to my channel.  I would also like the Function to post a message to the channel via client.chat.postMessage.  As far as I can see I have set everything up correctly but whenever I attempt to post the message I get an error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["User-Agent"]

The code to post the message is:

```
const { WebClient, LogLevel } = require("@slack/web-api");
const client = new WebClient(process.env['BOT_USER_OAUTH_TOKEN'], {
      // LogLevel can be imported and used to make debugging simpler
      logLevel: LogLevel.DEBUG
});

const channelId = "C0319MTLHB8";
try {
  // Call the chat.postMessage method using the WebClient
  const result = await client.chat.postMessage({
      channel: channelId,
      text: "Hello world"
  });
  console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
      body: "error: " + error
    };
}
```

and this piece of code sits within module.exports.

I guess something doesn't like the contents of BOT_USER_OAUTH_TOKEN but this is a direct copy of the xoxb bot user oauth token.  And is of the form:

xoxb-999999999999999-9999999999999-aBunchOfUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an open bracket in `const result = await client.chat.postMessage(` - maybe that's it?

Comment: Hi, thanks and well spotted.  However, it's a transcription error when I copied the code, my app has the correct syntax.  I have corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [I'm Joe Too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458149/im-joe-too) for your valuable discussed resolution. Posting as an answer to help other community members:

> You missed an open bracket in `const result = await client.chat.postMessage(`

> Glad @[JimBurke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12569519/jim-burke), that you have solved yourself by correcting the syntax/transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it Node.js 16 LTS?
I had a similar problem, But I made Node.js 14 LTS and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).